# Can an MPI worker suspend itself?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have built an MPI program in C++.

The program might be run in a distributed computing context, but it may also be run on a single machine. At initialization parameters are distributed to each worker. The workers then proceed in a parallel fashion without intercommunication. A partial result is returned to the master, more parameters are distributed, more fully parallel work is done, and the program terminates.

In the case of a single machine, the program's workers can be and will have to be run sequentially. The total data held by the program will not fit into RAM. A possible solution is to suspend worker processes at strategic points in time so that their memory can be swapped to disk and then reanimate them later to perform more calculations.

Is it possible to suspend a worker, say with `pthread_suspend` and reactivate it later?

Comment: Why would you create more than one worker in this case anyway?

Comment: In a distributed environment each process needs access to only part of the memory and the job can be completed this way. If one has access to only a single computer with limited memory, that same pattern, but performed sequentially, makes sense as a way to accomplish tasks that would otherwise be too large.

Comment: I have no idea what problem you are working on but if only one worker can be active at any time due to the machine's resource limitations, then it would seem logical that a single worker does all parts of the work sequentially in a loop.  Maybe that requires a radical design change (to allow *n* workers to do *m* parts of work with 1 ≤ *m* ≤ *n*) that you are not willing to commit to, I don't know.  I just wanted to point out that this might be an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks! A purely sequential design could not take advantage of a multicore/distributed system. For this particular problem, I think a parallel design could operate on a single-core/limited-memory system with only minor modifications, so the idea is worth exploring.

Comment: Go hybrid - have your MPI code combined with something like OpenMP in order to take advantage of the parallel processing capabilities of each node. Suspending/resuming threads takes a lot of CPU and I/O time that could be put into computing instead.

Comment: Certainly, @HristoIliev, but I do not think the OpenMP paradigm is well-suited to dealing with memory-limitation issues.